# Canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data via local chrome:// extension URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-extension, webgl

I am working on a google chrome extension and I am trying to load an image that is bundled with the extension into a canvas.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 470;
canvas.height = 470;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', function(){
     //process
});
image.src = chrome.extension.getURL("asset/gotcha.png");
```

When I execute the code in a content script I am getting:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been  tainted by 
cross-origin data.
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I have successfully embedded images, audio, video and flash directly into target sites without any those issues. The resource is listed under the web_accessible_resources in the manifest file.

Comment: What is the definition of `get_url` ?

Comment: get_url is local utility method that give me a chrome url ala chrome://1238901283908123098190/asset/gotcha.png

Comment: Why don't you use **[chrome.extension.getURL()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL)** ? Where is the above code run from ?

Comment: The code is deployed on three different extension systems/browsers,the method will handle the different ways of loading resources.

Comment: OK, all I wanted to know is that on Chrome it will invoke **chrome.extension.getURL()**. What about the other question: Where is the code run from (backgroundpage, content script, view, injected into a web-page) ?

Comment: Content script and embedded into webpage.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161471

Comment: See my answer based on ExpertSystem initial code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly pass an image from your extension to a web-page's canvas without making it tainted.
This is a work-around:

**Description:**

1. You access the image from your background page (or content script).
2. You put it in a canvas and convert it to a dataURL.
3. You inject some JS code into the web-page, passing the dataURL as a string.
4. The injected code uses the string (dataURL) to create an image (in the context of the web-page) and draw it onto a canvas.

**Sample code:**

```
/* In `background.js` */
function injectImg(tabID, remoteCanvasID, imgPath) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        var code = [
            "(function() {",
            "    var canvas = document.getElementById(\"" + remoteCanvasID + "\");",
            "    var img = new Image();",
            "    img.addEventListener(\"load\", function() {",
            "        canvas.getContext(\"2d\").drawImage(img, 0, 0);",
            "    });",
            "    img.src = \"" + dataURL + "\";",
            "    ",
            "})();"].join("\n");
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { code: code });
    });
    img.src = chrome.extension.getURL(imgPath);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender)) {
    if (msg.action && (msg.action == "getImg")
            && msg.imgPath && msg.canvasID) {
        injectImg(sender.tab.id, msg.canvasID, msg.imgPath);
    }
});

/* In `content.js` */
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getImg",
    imgPath: "some/image.png",
    canvasID: "someCanvasID"
});
```

This is a more generic approach (that can be used by any content script with minimum configuration), but it might be simpler to move part of the logic to the content script. E.g.:

- Define a function within the content script, that when called with a dataURL creates and draws an image onto a canvas.
- Define a function in the background page, that takes an image-path and returns a dataURL (as seen above).
- Use **chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()** to get a reference to the background page's `window` object, call the function to convert an image-path to a dataURL and finally use that dataURL to create an image and draw it onto a canvas.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [ExpertSystem's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896047/934239) I got a simple solution.

First part in the JavaScript of the background page where a canvas can be created without throwing a security exception.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == "convert_image_url_to_data_url") {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        sendResponse({data: canvas.toDataURL()}); 
      });
      img.src = request.url;
      return true; // Required for async sendResponse()
    }
  }
)
```

Second part for the content script:

```
//@success is the callback
function local_url_to_data_url(url, success) {  
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {message: "convert_image_url_to_data_url", url: url}, 
    function(response) {success(response.data)}
  );    
}
```

Comment: A little heads-up: **chrome.extension.onRequest** is deprecated. Use **chrome.runtime.onMessage** instead.

Comment: Also needs "return true" after setting the image source in order to run the callback asynchronously https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

Comment: Does not work in Chrome 44: ``Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.``

Answer (score 2):

Try to add your assets to the [`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html) property at the top-level of your manifest file, e.g.

```
    "web_accessible_resources": ["asset/gotcha.png"],
```

if you have not done so yet.