# Cross-origin permission for local file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, getimagedata

I would like to get the RGB pixel data of an image that I drag-and-drop to the browser, i.e. an image from my harddrive that is in the Chrome Active Tab.

I am not sure what permission I should ask for it in the manifest file, since the address of the image is "file:///C:/Users..."

If the image is on the web, then I can ask for cross-origin permission such as "https://*/*", and everything works, but for my local image I get an error: "The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

To get the pixel data I followed the direction of:

[How to get a pixel's x,y coordinate color from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774998/the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894948/canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-via-local-chrome-extension-url Or at least the answer provided may work for my problem as well, but I still have to try it.

Comment: Update: I was unable to utilize the solution in the above link. I get the same error message as before. The issue of overcoming the security error when trying to access RGB pixel data on an image which is stored on a local harddrive is for me still an open issue.